# Pandas sum of difference between rows

Tags: python, pandas

New to Pandas and I am using it to parse an excel file containing Employee data for IN/OUT timings received from the security records.
I wish to get values of diff for consecutive OUT - IN for the 'Type' column from the 'Log Time' Column and Get total number of OUT - IN - 1.
Thanks for the help, math makes my mind turn into jelly.

Sample data:

```
_________________________
| Emp | Log Time | Type |
-------------------------
| 001 | 9:30:00  |   IN |
-------------------------
| 001 | 9:35:00  | OUT  |
-------------------------
| 001 | 10:30:00 |  IN  |
-------------------------
| 001 | 18:30:00 | OUT  |
```

Expected output format:

```
      001
-------------------
| IN   | 9:30:00  |
-------------------
| OUT  | 18:30:00 |
-------------------
| TOTAL| 9:00:00  |
-------------------
| Work | 8:00:00  |
-------------------
| I/O  |   1      |
-------------------
```

Comment: To improve the question, you could at least show *some* attempt and describe why it wasn't enough. Or at the very least make it easier for other people to test on that data.

Comment: @Felix, thanks, most of my attempts have been towards messing with pandas library and I saw not much point in mentioning those disconnected attempts, agree about providing sample data. I was hoping to see people mention some strategies to tackle the problem and honestly I wouldn't have been able to think of stuff mentioned in below answer such as `reset_index`, `df.concat` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a `df` (input dataframe) of this format:

```
>>print(df)

   EMP  LOG TIME    TYPE
0   1   09:30:15    IN
1   1   10:30:15    OUT
2   1   11:30:15    IN
3   1   17:30:15    OUT
4   2   09:30:15    IN
5   2   10:15:15    OUT
6   2   11:05:28    IN
7   2   18:30:15    OUT
```

You can use `groupby` based on the `EMP` value and find the `min` for `IN` and `max` for `OUT`. The code is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
df1 = df[df['TYPE'] == 'IN'].groupby(['EMP']).min().reset_index()
df1 = df1.rename(index=str, columns={"LOG TIME": "LOG TIME IN", "TYPE": "TYPE IN"})
df2 = df[df['TYPE'] == 'OUT'].groupby(['EMP']).max().reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename(index=str, columns={"LOG TIME": "LOG TIME OUT", "TYPE": "TYPE OUT"})
df2 = df2.drop(['EMP'],axis=1)
```

You can now use `concat` and merge both the dataframes row-wise and subtract the two columns and put the results in the as a new column.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
total_hrs = []
for index,row in df3.iterrows():
    total_hrs.append(datetime.strptime(str(row['LOG TIME OUT']),'%H:%M:%S') - 
                     datetime.strptime(str(row['LOG TIME IN']),'%H:%M:%S'))
df3['TOTAL HOURS'] = total_hrs
```

Hope this helps you in basic understanding. Try to formulate your question a little bit by providing us a test data.

Comment: @sol Glad to know it helped you .You can upvote the answer.Cheers